Apache Flink 1.18 Mongo sink Connector. SSL configuration problem
I'm trying to use MongoSink inside AWS Managed Apache Flink to write messages to a DocumentDb collection. It's working fine if the cluster does not have SSL/TLS enabled. If I enabled TLS/SSL the sink will not work, because doesn't have SSL context configured.
I was checking the code inside MongoWriter and I saw that mongoClient is initialized just using connection URI
// Initialize the mongo client.
this.mongoClient = MongoClients.create(connectionOptions.getUri());

I've tested a dedicated mongo client with the SSL settings applyToSslSettings and i was abled to connect without problems.
Anyone knows how i can handler with this problem on Mongo Sink?
Thanks

In fact, Initialized use connection URI is enough, and specify tls=true as a query parameter, as in:
mongodb://user:password@127.0.0.1:8081/?tls=true

then configure four system properties, accroding to this.
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=D:\tmp\store.trust -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=123456 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=D:\tmp\store.keys -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=123456

store.trust come from
keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -file root.crt -keystore store.trust

store.keys come from
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mongo.p12 -destkeystore store.keys -srcstoretype pkcs12

About mongo.p12 you can read this.
Anyway, it passed my test.

Sorry, i forgot to say that we are running inside AWS Managed Apache Flink. We don't have access to Cluster initialization to pass java parameters. That is the real problem. Thanks for your answer
